# PHP Fatal Error with Userfrosting now server always shows Error 500

Tags: php, facade, userfrosting

I was managing my server and after a composer update I receive this message:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to UserFrosting\System\Facade::setFacadeContainer() must be an instance of Interop\Container\ContainerInterface, instance of Slim\Container given, called in /home/arteller/www/userfrosting/app/system/UserFrosting.php on line 53 and defined in /home/arteller/www/userfrosting/app/system/Facade.php:210

After this, I receive only 500 Internal Error from my server. 
The error persists every time I also try to use the command **"php bakery bake"** or something related to bakery.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please share some code snippet as the error pasted does not clarify what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to UserFrosting [4.3.3](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/releases/tag/v4.3.3) or later, and run `composer update` again. This issue was introduced by Slim, which [introduced a breaking change recently](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/pull/2885#issuecomment-559636640).